# How to port default android camera? Any open source camera?

Tags: android

I'm building a simple camera app with a preview overlay on top of a camera. It will include some basic functions such as flash on/auto/off, zoom-in-out, and using the front and back camera.

However, I tried to get the source from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git but there seems to be missing the LaunchPerformanceBase class. Anyone know where to find it? Any tutorials on how to compile the camera?

Also, I am sure someone has done a similar one before. Can anyone point me the direction of the source codes of a similar one if there is any?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The android documentation already thoroughly covers the topic of integrating the device's Camera in your application.  Have a read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Yah, but I find the guide n